# How to control overflow of a div within a table cell that may span multiple rows

Tags: css, html-table

If am working on a scheduling page that has a row for each hour of the day, and a column for each day of the week.  Some cells can span multiple rows (using `rowspan`) if the occur for multiple hours - a typical calendar situation.  Each `TD` contains a `DIV` with the event information I would like to control.  Additionally, each column must have a width of 12.5% (a col for the time, and 7 for each day)

In short, I would like the `div` contents to use *whatever space is available in the cell*.  If the `td` spans 4 rows, it should use all that space and allow wrapping to include as much of the text as will fit, but if the rowspan is only 1, then it should only display 1 line and hide anything beyond that.

I've tried most of the solutions I've found on SE and other sites, but they all interfere with the consistent column width, or with the row height.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using run the code Snippet or find the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6v4LkLg/)

```css
.demo {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.demo td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.ID {
  width: 10%;
}
.email {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table class="demo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="ID">ID</th>
      <th class="email">Email<th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>pradyumnaswain76@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way here is to style the `<div>` you don't want to resize, because the height of the row is determined according to the content size (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout).

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/vz3muoq8/2/

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td rowspan="3">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>aaa</td></tr>

    <tr><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td><div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>

</table>
```

#### CSS

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height:15px;
    text-wrap: ellipsis;
}

div {
    height: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Haven't had much luck with this...*every* TD contains a div, which seems to be where my problem is lying.